# Subsetting an object in R by character sequence

Tags: r, grouping, subset

I would like to subset an object in R according to the suffixes of the barcodes it contains. These end in '-n' where n is a number from 1 to 6. e.g. AAACCGTGCCCTCA-1, GAACCGTGCCCTCA-2, CATGCGTGCCCTCA-5, etc. I would like all the corresponding information about each barcode to be split accordingly as well. Here is some example code of an object, cds.

```
grp = sub("[A-Z]*[-]","",cds$barcodes)
group1 = cds[,grp==1]
```

However, when I view group1, I get

```
> group1$barcode
factor(0)
7047 Levels: AAACATACCAGTTG-3 AAACATACTATGCG-4 AAACATTGAAGCCT-5 AAACATTGGCGAAG-4 AAACATTGTGAAGA-4     ... TTTGCATGGCCAAT-5
```

and all the barcodes are still there. I also don't want to substitute the barcodes for the number at the end - I just want a way of telling R to locate a specific barcode by the number it ends in, so I can group them, but to keep the barcodes as they are.

For example, I would like group1$barcodes to look something like this:

```
group1$barcode
1   AAACCGTGCCCTCA-1
2   AAACGCACACGCAT-1
3   AAACGGCTTCCGAA-1
4   AAAGACGAACCCAA-1
5   AAAGACGACTGTTT-1
6   AAAGAGACAAAGCA-1
7   AAAGATCTGGTAAA-1
8   AAAGCAGAGCAAGG-1
9   AAAGCAGATTATCC-1
10  AAAGCCTGATGACC-1
```

Many thanks!

Abigail

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example and show the expected output based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit:

Use 'suffix' not 'prefix'!

I'd suggest using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
cds %>%
mutate(grp = gsub("([A-Z]*)-([0-9]+)", "\\2", barcodes))
```

And then to filter single groups:

```
cds %>%
  mutate(grp = gsub("([A-Z]*)-([0-9]+)", "\\2", barcodes)) %>% 
  filter(grp == 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I still get this though: > grp = sub("[A-Z]*[-]","",cds$barcodes),
> group1 = cds[,grp==1],
> group1$barcode
factor(0)
7047 Levels: AAACATACCAGTTG-3 AAACATACTATGCG-4 AAACATTGAAGCCT-5 AAACATTGGCGAAG-4 AAACATTGTGAAGA-4 ... TTTGCATGGCCAAT-5.

Comment: (There should be around 2000 with the -1 suffix)

Comment: Oh I forgot to run the first part, but now it says: Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('CellDataSet', 'ExpressionSet', 'eSet', 'VersionedBiobase', 'Versioned')". I think the class is the problem :-(

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) it's kind of difficult to know what you are seeing or where the problem lies... but do you mean the part about `levels`??

Comment: You can try `as.data.frame(object_that_is_a_different_class`

Comment: OR `cds_df <- data.frame(barcodes = as.character(cds$barcodes))`